# E93: More than one match when <C-d> shows only one match

Tags: buffers, autocompletion, multiple-files, filenames

When jumping between buffers in Vim, most the time things work quite smoothly.

I like to jump to buffers by writing `:b something1*something2`, checking if the match is unique by invoking `C-d`, and if so executing the command. However, for certain files, Vim gives `E93: More than one match` despite `C-d` giving only one result.

Why is this so, and how can I fix it?

Edit:

As noted in the comments, I myself don't always run into the issue; clearly this issue is not "supposed" to happen and is not triggered on typical cases, making it non-trivial to reproduce...

Finally, I've run into the issue again and managed to produce a file structure that appears to demonstrate the issue.

First, create this file tree in the shell:

```
mkdir test-vim-1
cd test-vim-1

mkdir -p src/app/jargon/views/
mkdir -p src/app/jargon/views/ProfileEditBottomSheetView/
mkdir -p src/app/jargon/views/ProfileEditBottomSheetView/
mkdir -p src/app/jargon/views/CheckInBottomSheetView/
mkdir -p src/app/jargon/views/pages/my-account/
mkdir -p src/app/jargon/views/ProfileEditBottomSheetView/
mkdir -p src/app/jargon/views/pages/home/
mkdir -p src/app/jargon/views/LanguagesBottomSheetView/
mkdir -p src/app/jargon/views/pages/coffee-house-detail/
mkdir -p src/app/jargon/views/
mkdir -p src/app/jargon/views/pages/chat/
mkdir -p src/app/jargon/views/pages/coffee-house-detail/
touch src/app/jargon/views/ShareWithFriendsBottomSheetView.js 
touch src/app/jargon/views/ProfileEditBottomSheetView/ProfileEditBottomSheetView.js 
touch src/app/jargon/views/ProfileEditBottomSheetView/ProfileImageControl.js 
touch src/app/jargon/views/CheckInBottomSheetView/CheckInBottomSheetView.js 
touch src/app/jargon/views/pages/my-account/OptionsMenuBottomSheetView.js 
touch src/app/jargon/views/ProfileEditBottomSheetView/profile-edit-bottom-sheet-view-terms.js 
touch src/app/jargon/views/pages/home/CoffeeHouseSearchBottomSheetView.js 
touch src/app/jargon/views/LanguagesBottomSheetView/LanguagesBottomSheetView.js 
touch src/app/jargon/views/pages/coffee-house-detail/ViewMemberBottomSheetView.js 
touch src/app/jargon/views/BottomSheetLayout.js 
touch src/app/jargon/views/pages/chat/AllReactionsBottomSheetView.js 
touch src/app/jargon/views/pages/coffee-house-detail/AddAdminBottomSheetView.js
```

Now, open vim, and open all the files (replace  with your $PWD or `test-vim-1`):

```
:e /<path-to-dir>/src/app/jargon/views/ShareWithFriendsBottomSheetView.js | e /<path-to-dir>/src/app/jargon/views/ProfileEditBottomSheetView/ProfileEditBottomSheetView.js | e /<path-to-dir>/src/app/jargon/views/ProfileEditBottomSheetView/ProfileImageControl.js | e /<path-to-dir>/src/app/jargon/views/CheckInBottomSheetView/CheckInBottomSheetView.js | e /<path-to-dir>/src/app/jargon/views/pages/my-account/OptionsMenuBottomSheetView.js | e /<path-to-dir>/src/app/jargon/views/ProfileEditBottomSheetView/profile-edit-bottom-sheet-view-terms.js | e /<path-to-dir>/src/app/jargon/views/pages/home/CoffeeHouseSearchBottomSheetView.js | e /<path-to-dir>/src/app/jargon/views/LanguagesBottomSheetView/LanguagesBottomSheetView.js | e /<path-to-dir>/src/app/jargon/views/pages/coffee-house-detail/ViewMemberBottomSheetView.js | e /<path-to-dir>/src/app/jargon/views/BottomSheetLayout.js | e /<path-to-dir>/src/app/jargon/views/pages/chat/AllReactionsBottomSheetView.js | e /<path-to-dir>/src/app/jargon/views/pages/coffee-house-detail/AddAdminBottomSheetView.js
```

Finally, now type `: b Bot`, and `<C-d>` will somehow only produce `src/app/jargon/views/BottomSheetLayout.js` even though every other buffer contains the substring "Bot", and pressing Enter will produce the stated error.

(`:version` tells us that my vim is "VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0", "Included patches: 1-1441")

Comment: What version of Vim?

Comment: `:version` reports `VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28) Included patches: 1-1441`

Comment: This seems like a bug of some sort. Do you have any plugins running?

Comment: No, I haven't got any. Any suggestions find the issue? I notice that sometimes this occurs when another buffer with a similar name is in my loaded buffers. However, given that <C-d> only returns one match, I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried moving your vimrc aside temporarily?

Comment: Would be good to have a way to reproduce it. Do you have a procedure to do so?

Comment: Good point. Let me do some experiments.

Comment: Following up: I can't reproduce this with `vim -u DEFAULTS -u NONE`, `:edit foobar`, and `:b f*r<C-d><enter>`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I've noticed that this occurs mostly in long vim sessions with thousands of buffers; in these cases, there *are* in fact multiple matches for the pattern provided to `:b`, but the problem is that <C-d> only shows one of the matches. Perhaps deleted files may be related? The thing is, this only occurs when I have a fairly long vim session and thus is hard to give a reproduction of.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this with 2^16 buffers (using this script: https://gist.github.com/benknoble/6c53d17d68c7b6b267ac2e6753930094)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm astounded by the test you put together; I'm guessing the issue is not in the completions itself, I'm now guessing its more due to the completions display line? Somehow I haven't run into this again lately; if I manage to reproduce this better, I'll post the info here.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I've managed to reproduce the issue, and edited my question to include the test case! See if you can reproduce the issue on your end.

Comment: You should open an issue. This isite is not an issue tracker.

Comment: I thought I must have produced some common mistake when I first posted the question and did not think it was a bug, so I asked about this over here. Let me file this as an issue on the vim github as well.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, this is a bug (or should I say feature?), that the buffer completion code always favors patterns matching beginning of line or being anchored to directory separators and if it finds matches for such buffers, does not consider to try to match the pattern elsewhere in the buffer name.

I have now fixed this with Vim patch [9.1.0131](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/0dc0bff000fd804c6b0778ccc4554a4e4c82c8c9), read the commit message discussing this feature/bug.

Comment: I've replied in the issue - I don't think your explanation about <C-d> explicitly anchoring to beginning of file name is correct regarding vim's behavior.